# UWP: Reveal full, unclipped ImageBrush on tapped event

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I have a series of rectangles in which the user can add images to, by dragging the images in.
The image is then scaled down in proportion and the rectangle is then filled with an ImageBrush.

I need for the user to be able to manipulate the image within the rectangle to fit their needs. Like any photo collage app does.

My question is: How can I show the full, unmasked image on top of the rectangle so that the user can manipulate it to their needs?  I don't know where to start with this one.

```
     private async void Mask_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle maskSq = e.OriginalSource as Rectangle;

        var maskW = maskSq.Width.ToSingle();
        var maskH = maskSq.Height.ToSingle();
        double maskX = Canvas.GetLeft(maskSq);
        double maskY = Canvas.GetTop(maskSq);

        // Image sizes for bounding to mask
        float boundH = Convert.ToSingle(size.Height);
        float boundW = Convert.ToSingle(size.Width);

        maskSq.Fill = new ImageBrush
        {
            ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/" + SelectedImage.Name, UriKind.Absolute)),
            Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill
        };
   }

    private void Tap_Collage(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Gets the full image from ImageBrush
        ImageBrush brush = (ImageBrush)(((Rectangle)sender).Fill);
        Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;

        //Mask sure rectangle does not drag, just the image brush
        rect.CanDrag = false;
        rect.StrokeThickness = 6;

        //Drag Image Functionality
        rect.ManipulationDelta += ImageManipulation.Resize_ImageEdit;
        ImageManipulation.ImageEdit_Drag = new TranslateTransform();
        brush.Transform = ImageManipulation.ImageEdit_Drag;

        //Zoom Image Functionality
        ImageManipulation.ImageEdit_Zoom = new ScaleTransform();
        brush.RelativeTransform = ImageManipulation.ImageEdit_Zoom;

    }
```

Class

```
public static class ImageManipulation
{
    public static TranslateTransform ImageEdit_Drag;
    public static ScaleTransform ImageEdit_Zoom;
    public static RotateTransform ImageEdit_Rotate;

    public static void Resize_ImageEdit(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageEdit_Drag.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        ImageEdit_Drag.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

        ImageEdit_Zoom.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
        ImageEdit_Zoom.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;

        if (ImageEdit_Zoom.ScaleX < 1.0)
        {
            ImageEdit_Zoom.ScaleX = 1.0;
            ImageEdit_Zoom.ScaleY = 1.0;
        }

        ImageEdit_Rotate.Angle += e.Delta.Rotation;
    }

}
```

XAML

```
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CollageGrid">
                <Rectangle Width="{Binding CollageW}" Height="{Binding CollageH}" AllowDrop="True" CanDrag="True" Fill="Transparent"
                    Drop="Mask_Drop"  
                    DragOver="Mask_DragOver"
                    ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" DragEnter="Mask_DragEnter" DragLeave="Mask_DragLeave" Tapped="Tap_Collage">
                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding CollageX}" Y="{Binding CollageY}"/>
                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Example of what I'm looking to acheive:

[image: Example of what I'm looking to acheive]

How it looks currently:

[image: How it looks Currently]

Comment: I don't have an answer now, but maybe you can use some effects outside of the rectangle, like a blur. I think you can give a look at Windows Community Toolkit

Comment: Adding a blur to the imageBrush is fine and simple to do. However, my issue is that I don't know how to access the parts of the image that are outside of the rectangle. By default, the rectangle "masks off" any excess parts of the image and so the only part of the image that is visible is the area that actually fits in the rectangle... if that makes sense.

Comment: So your question is operating the image to fit the Rectangle? Do you try the [Manipulation events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/touch-interactions#manipulation-events)?

Comment: Okay, I've managed to work half a solution using manipulationDelta, I can now drag and edit the imageBrush. The problem is that I still can't figure out how to visually display the areas of the ImageBrush that are outside of the rectangle bounds, it's a small issue but a necessary one.

Comment: @AdamMcMahon I am not sure what is the detail that your Xaml looks like now and maybe I lost on your direction. But you can try the [BackdropBlurBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.media.backdropblurbrush?view=uwp-toolkit-dotnet) on the community toolkit.

Comment: XAML has remained the same as the above. I'll try to explain my issue better... I'm using a rectangle for the bounds and then when the user drags an image into it, I fill the rectangle with an ImageBrush and stretch UniformToFill which shrinks the ImageBrush down to fit the rectangle as best as it can. The problem with this is that it only shows the area of the ImageBrush that is inside the rectangle, I have no idea on how to access the rest of the ImagBrush in order to display it outside of the rectangle. Your help with using the manipulation events helped me a lot, I'll update my code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace the Rectangle with the [Polyline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Polyline) to draw the Rectangle so that you can access the Image which is on the bottom of the Rectangle.

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="Assets/image1.jpg" Width="800"
           Height="400" Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
    <Polyline Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
    StrokeThickness="4" Tapped="Polyline_Tapped"
    Points="0,0,0,200,200,200,200,0,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

---**Update**---

`UniformToFill` will cause the image is resized to fill the destination dimensions while it preserves its native aspect ratio. If the aspect ratio of the destination rectangle differs from the source, the source content is clipped to fit in the destination dimensions. So it is not suitable for your requirement. You should manually scale the Image to make image fit one of your Rectangle's border and keep other part out of the Rectangle.

It seems you put the image as the Rectangle's background image brush, there are no other place to display the image out of the Rectangle. So I think, we may take a considerition for a new scenario.

As my pervious reply, using Image control to display the image and Polylines to draw a Rectangle above the Image so that we can operate the Image which is below the Rectangle using the manipulation events to fit the rectangle, meanwhile we can also use the community toolkit [BackdropBlurBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.media.backdropblurbrush?view=uwp-toolkit-dotnet) on the xaml layout to Blur the outer image.

Comment: Can you explain why this is better than simply using a rectangle? I could access the image underneath a rectangle if indeed I was placing the image underneath my rectangle. Changing to a polyline just over complicates it without solving anything, unless there's something I'm missing? I've updated my question with the addition of my XAML in case it helps. Thanks

Comment: @AdamMcMahon I add the update part to clarify my scenario, you can have a check.